# Catch wrong input within dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to display the error message "This doesn't work" when a user enters an input that does not match a key in the dict. Currently, when they enter a correct input (ie, "Audi" or "Ferrari", It'll display the "This works, Audi" but If incorrectly entered, nothing happens. Why? I could easily do it with if/elif but I want to tackle the error handling side. Thanks

```
while car_search !="Q" or car_search !="q":
    try:
        if car_search in car_dict.keys():
            car = car_dict[car_search]
            print("This works", car.make)
    except KeyError:
        print("This doesn't work")
```

Comment: because you've got an if statement that avoids the error, delete line 3

Comment: `car_search` will always be different than Q or different than q. For the loop to terminate `car_search` would need to be both "Q" and "q"

Comment: @Sayse Thanks this is exactly what I was missing. So removing that line, does line 4 effectively do the same thing as line 3? But with the assistance of try: ? I thought I would have to keep the if statement to actually search the dict.keys. It does work, thank you! I would just like to know...how

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I've added breaks in sorry I forgot to in the code snippet

Comment: simpler to use `if car := car_dict.get(car_search):` than check if car_search in car_dict.keys(). The ' :=' assigns the value to 'car' variable as part of the call. If car_search not in list then value is None and expression evaluates to False.

Comment: you might be interested in reading EAFP (easier to ask for forgiveness than permission) vs LBYL (look before you leap) https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/idiomatic-python-eafp-versus-lbyl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I corrected a bit your code and added comments

```
# if you want to capture both a lowercase and uppercase characters, 
# you can do something like:
# notice you might need a rstrip to eliminate newline characters
# in case your search_car comes from a console input
while car_search.lower().rstrip() != "q":
    # this is the EAFP approach. Try accessing the key, and handle 
    # the exception if the key does not exist
    try:
        car = car_dict[car_search]
        print("This works", car.make)
    except KeyError:
        print("This doesn't work")

    # here you have to request a new car_search,
    # otherwise you will run again and again the same option
    car_search = input("Input a car to search (q to exit)")
```

You can also use the LBYL approach, so you first check if the key exist before trying to access it.

```
while car_search.lower().rstrip() != "q":
    if car_search in car_dict.keys():
        print("This works", car.make)
    else
        print("This doesn't work")

    car_search = input("Input a car to search (q to exit)")
```